# Chrome extension: devtools protocol timeout

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-devtools-protocol

My extn uses the [devtools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) (`debugger` permission); after it has attached the debugger - it needs to stay attached indefinitely, to monitor changes on the attached to tab, etc.
Keeping it running overnight turned out that after some period of time - the debugger flipped off.

Is there some built-in timeout for `debugger.attach` command, after which it automatically detaches itself?